# inconveniente al consultar datos desde base de datos con Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql

Hola buenas noches me comunico para comentarles un inconveniente que tengo en un ejercicio de python tkinter y mysql. Resulta que tengo un formulario de Carga de articulos y que tambien consulta los mismos. La carga la realiza sin problemas, a la consulta no, en el cuadro de entrada de consultas deberia setearse al resultado de la busqueda pero por algun motivo que ignoro no sucede lo siguiente. Les adjunto el codigo de consulta(formulario) y el de la base de datos.

```
        self.articulo=dat.articulo()# debemos relacionar cada clase con la base de datos con la cual trabajeremos
        self.ventana_de_consulta=t.Tk()
        self.interfaz_consulta()
        self.ventana_de_consulta.mainloop()


    def interfaz_consulta(self):  
        self.label_codigo_consulta=ttk.Label(self.ventana_de_consulta,   text="codigo")    
        self.label_codigo_consulta.grid(column=1,   row=2,  padx=5, pady=5)
        self.codigo=t.StringVar()
        self.entrada_codigo_consulta=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_de_consulta,    width=10,   textvariable=self.codigo)
        self.entrada_codigo_consulta.grid(column=2, row=2,  padx=5, pady=5)

        self.label_descripcion_consulta=ttk.Label(self.ventana_de_consulta, text="Descripcion")
        self.label_descripcion_consulta.grid(column=1,  row=3,  padx=5, pady=5)
        self.funcion_descripcion=t.StringVar()
        self.entrada_descripcion_consulta=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_de_consulta,   width=10,   textvariable=self.funcion_descripcion, state="readonly")
        self.entrada_descripcion_consulta.grid(column=2,    row=3,  padx=5, pady=5)


        self.label_precio_consulta=ttk.Label(self.ventana_de_consulta, text="PRECIO")
        self.label_precio_consulta.grid(column=1,   row=4,  padx=5, pady=5)
        self.funcion_precio_consulta=t.StringVar()
        self.entrada_precio_consulta=ttk.Entry(self.ventana_de_consulta,   width=10,   textvariable=self.funcion_precio_consulta, state="readonly")
        self.entrada_precio_consulta.grid(column=2, row=4,  padx=5, pady=5)

        self.boton_consulta=ttk.Button(self.ventana_de_consulta,    text="Consultar", command=self.consultar  )
        self.boton_consulta.grid(column=3,  row=5,  padx=5, pady=5)

    
    def consultar(self):
        datos_2=(self.codigo.get(), )
        respuesta=self.articulo.consulta(datos_2)
        if len (respuesta) >0:
            self.funcion_descripcion.set(respuesta[0][0])
            self.funcion_precio_consulta.set(respuesta[0][1])
        else:
            self.funcion_descripcion.set("")
            self.funcion_precio_consulta.set("")
            messagebox.showinfo("ERROR","NO SE ENCONTRO EL PRODUCTO")
```

Conexion base de datos

````
class articulo:

    def abrir(self):
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",   user="root",    passwd="",  database="baseprueba")
        return conexion

    def alta(self,datos):
        cone=self.abrir()
        cursor=cone.cursor()
        sql="insert into  articulos( codigo, descripcion, precio) values(%s, %s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)
        cone.commit()
        cone.close()

    
    def consulta(self,datos_2):
        cone=self.abrir()
        cursor=cone.cursor()
        sql="select descripcion , precio from articulos where codigo=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, datos_2)
        cone.close()
        return cursor. fetchall() ```
````

Comment: Estas cerrando la conexion antes de traer los registros?

Comment: si, se cierra la conexion antes de traerlos, luego de eso debe retornar

Comment: Tendrá que ver qué: tengo la clase para cargar y otra clase para consulta?  Podría venir por ahí el inconveniente?